# Align some descendants to bottom, and some to top

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-zstack

As a root view of my app, I have a `ZStack`, and I would like to add two floating bars, one to the bottom, and one to the top of the viewport.

With a single bar it's easy (`ZStack(alignment: .top)`), but is there a way to add multiple descendants, and have one aligned to the top, and a second one to the bottom?

I tried removing `alignment` from ZStack, and adding `.frame(alignment: .top)` / `.frame(alignment: .bottom)` to the children, but this didn't do anything.

Yes, it could be hacked around by wrapping a top-aligned ZStack with another, bottom-aligned one, but it seems rather inelegant.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Here is possible approach

```
ZStack {

 // content here

}
.overlay(YourTopView(), alignment: .top)
.overlay(YourBottomView(), alignment: .bottom)
```

Other possible variant is to use one `.overlay` with `VStack` having two views and `Spacer` in between.

Answer (score 6):

Here's another approach that allows overlap of the top and bottom-aligned views.

```
ZStack() {
    VStack() {
        topView()
        Spacer()
    }
    VStack() {
        Spacer()
        bottomView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just add a `VStack` inside your `ZStack` like this

```swift
ZStack {
    VStack {
        YourTopView()
        Spacer()
        YourBottomView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this also works - I originally expected the spacer to block clicks into underlying content, but it apparently doesn't.